How to create custom span renderer with gesture events in MAUI
I have a MAUI project (.Net 7). I would like to creating custom span renderer (only android and ios) with gesture events. But I didn't find any documentation, workarounds etc. How can I do it?
I readed maui documentation but I don't find any workaround,example..

That may relate to the known issue, Gestures don't work on Label Spans, which is fixed in .NET8. You can add the gesture recognizer for the span using .NET8 like this,
<Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="default, " FontSize="14">
                <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" />
                </Span.GestureRecognizers>
            </Span>
           ...

By the way, .NET7 is now out of support, we recommend you use the latest .NET8 for you application.
For more info, please refer to Use formatted text.
